# inorder method at BinaryTree in Java (array implementation)

Tags: java, arrays, binary-tree, inorder

How to write a correct inorder-method for my binary-tree implementation?

This is my test-try:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree myTree = new BinaryTree();
        myTree.inorder(0);
    } 
}

public class BinaryTree {
    char[] tree = {'k', 'q', 'r', 'g', 'e', 'i', 'y', 'p', 'l', 'b', 'x', 'm', 'g', 't', 'u', 'v', 'z'};
    public void inorder(int node) {
        if(node < tree.length) {
            inorder((node * 2));
            System.out.print(tree[node] + " ");
            inorder(((node * 2) + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Love to help what are you trying to do here

Comment: Can you post what your problem is exactly?  What's wrong?  What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myTree.inorder(0); // parameter : 0

inorder((node * 2));  // node = 0, node * 2 = 0,

Therefore, the parameters will continue to be zero is an infinite loop.

```java
public class BinaryTree {
    char[] tree = {'k', 'q', 'r', 'g', 'e', 'i', 'y', 'p', 'l', 'b', 'x', 'm', 'g', 't', 'u', 'v', 'z'};
    public void inorder(int node) {
        if(node < tree.length) {
            inorder((node * 2) + 1);
            System.out.print(tree[node] + " ");
            inorder(((node * 2) + 2));
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        tree.inorder(0);
    }
}
```